# Python Reportlab spacing or gap between table cells

Tags: python-3.x, reportlab

I would like to add a spacing between the middle cells of this table in reportlab but don't find any relevant info in the documentation to do it.

Tried this code but do not know if I need to generate separate tables.

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import inch
from reportlab.platypus import Table, SimpleDocTemplate
from reportlab.lib import colors
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("label.pdf", pagesize=(4 * inch, 6 * inch))
content = []
data= [
['Name', 'John Week', 'NO. 1234'],
['5678', ' ', ' '],
['Aisle', '3' , ' '],
['Table', '2', ' '],
['Location', 'Continental', ' '],
['Units moved', '40', ' '],
['Units pending', '10', ' '],
['Total', '50', ' '],
['Number', '1 of 50', ' '],
]
t=Table(data,colWidths=[1.2*inch,1.4*inch,0.8*inch],style=[
('FONTSIZE', (0,0), (-1,-1), 7),
('ALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'CENTER'),
('VALIGN',(0,0),(-1,-1),'MIDDLE'),
('GRID',(1,2),(-2,-1),1,colors.black),
('BOX',(0,1),(0,1),1,colors.black),
('BOX',(2,0),(2,1),1,colors.black),
])
content.append(t)
doc.build(content)
```

Current result:

[image: current result]

I would like to obtain the following:
[image: expected]

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want, but the closest I can produce with little effort:

[image: spaced table]

This is achieved by drawing thicker grid lines between the cells and erasing their interior, i. e. adding the style commands:

```
('INNERGRID', (1,2), (1,7), 4, colors.black),
('LINEABOVE', (1,3), (1,7), 2, colors.white),
```